# HTML , CSS how to scroll infinite with multiple position sticky and without using overflow

Tags: html, css

hello i have a two elements of `position sticky` 1st is **NAV LIST** with background of ORANGE, 2nd is **HOME** with background of PINK. now my goal is when i am scrolling i want to stick the **Home** while continuing scrolling other contents. but i don't have a idea how to do that.. the best way i did is i used `overflow:scroll` to hide other elements and  achieve that goal. but i don't want to show other scrollbar like overflow. i want the only one default of scrollbar.

here is my code that i wrote

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.first {
  height:50px;
  background:orange;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

.second {
  height:90vh;
  background:pink;
  position:sticky;
  top:90px;
}

section{
    text-align: center; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color:white;
}
ul{
    text-align: center; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color:white; flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<section style="height: 90vh !important; font-size: 2rem; background: purple; ">
    <h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
</section>
<section   class="first"  style="height: 10vh !important; font-size: 1rem; background: orange;">
    <h1>THIS IS A NAV LIST</h1>
</section>

<section  style="height: 90vh; font-size: 2rem; background: cornflowerblue;">
    THIS IS A CONTENT 1
</section>
<div class="second" style="display: flex; overflow-y: hidden;">
        <div style="flex:1;">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li>ABOUT</li>
                <li>PAGE</li>
                <li>LOGIN</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="flex:3; overflow-y: scroll;">
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: green; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 2
            </section>
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: skyblue; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 3
            </section>
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: brown; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 4
            </section>
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: violet; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 5
            </section>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to use only one scroll bar right?

Comment: yes only. the default scroll bar we use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide this way lets try

**CSS**

```
.hide-scrollbar{
    overflow: scroll;
}

.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: transparent; //this will hide the scrollbar
    width: 0px;
}
```

**Div tag**

```
<div class="hide-scrollbar"></div>
```

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.hide-scrollbar {
   overflow: scroll;
}

.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
   background: transparent;
   width: 0px;
 }

.first {
  height:50px;
  background:orange;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

.second {
  height:90vh;
  background:pink;
  position:sticky;
  top:90px;
}

section{
    text-align: center; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color:white;
}
ul{
    text-align: center; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color:white; flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<section style="height: 90vh !important; font-size: 2rem; background: purple; ">
    <h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
</section>
<section   class="first"  style="height: 10vh !important; font-size: 1rem; background: orange;">
    <h1>THIS IS A NAV LIST</h1>
</section>

<section  style="height: 90vh; font-size: 2rem; background: cornflowerblue;">
    THIS IS A CONTENT 1
</section>
<div class="second" style="display: flex; overflow-y: hidden;">
        <div style="flex:1;">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li>ABOUT</li>
                <li>PAGE</li>
                <li>LOGIN</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="flex:3;" class="hide-scrollbar"> <!-- changes here-->
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: green; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 2
            </section>
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: skyblue; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 3
            </section>
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: brown; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 4
            </section>
            <section style="height: 100vh; font-size: 2rem; background: violet; ">
                THIS IS A CONTENT 5
            </section>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but if i hide that it will not scroll and show the other contents

Comment: hover the mouse to content and try again its working

Comment: oh i see thank you. i think this one is good. but how about not using hover or clicking when scrolling some of users maybe don't know that the other contents need to hover or click  to continue scrolling

Comment: In content of bottom, you can add small icon for scroll bar down, this will let know to the user